# Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)

Tags: react-native

Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a clean installation from the beginning, I think something must have been missing.